# Concatenating multiple rows in one query

Tags: mysql, performance

I have two tables with the following design

- `movies` : ID,name
- `genres`:  movie_id, genre

Each movie can have more than one genre.

I wish to list all movies and their genres, so I'd get something like:

```
name1 genre1,genre2,genre3
name2 genre2,genre6,genre8
```

etc.

And I want to be able to do it using a single query (I'm using MySQL 5.6).

I thought about using concatenate but can't manage to make it actually work. any thoughts?

Comment: You should normalize your tables a bit more. Add a table movie2genre with movie_id, genre_id and a seperate table genre.

Comment: @JensW. If you look at the question, it is normalized. `movies` tables has `(ID,Name)`, while `genres` has `(movie_id,genre)`.

Comment: That is not normalized. Each genre name will be stored multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

The query for you

```
select m.name, group_concat(g.genre) from movies m, genres g
where m.id = g.movie_id group by m.name;
```

Here is some sample data:

```
mysql> create table movies (id int, name varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> create table genres (movie_id int, genre varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into movies values (1, 'Terminator');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into movies values (2, 'Lord of the Rings');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into genres values (1, 'action');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into genres values (1, 'sci-fi');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into genres values (2, 'fantasy');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into genres values (2, 'adventure');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

Here is the output of the query:

```
mysql> select m.name, group_concat(g.genre) from movies m, genres g where m.id = g.movie_id group by m.name;
+-------------------+-----------------------+
| name              | group_concat(g.genre) |
+-------------------+-----------------------+
| Lord of the Rings | adventure,fantasy     |
| Terminator        | sci-fi,action         |
+-------------------+-----------------------+
```